# Xamarin Studio always prompting to "load from autosave", or load the "original file", bug

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

A quick look into the Xamarin bug tracker says that the autosave bug (I describe below) has hit people from time to time on various projects.  This bug was closed as end-user resolved (developer gave up?), or unable to reproduce.

[image]

Here I'm loading "Sport", a pre-assembled sample, produced by Xamarin.  Randomly, the autosave dialog on the left pops up.  This happens when I

1. Switch between tabs
2. Reopen a closed tab, load from autosave, then save again.
3. Load the project from scratch (random)

In situation #2, other classes that depend on the closed tab will be unable to locate the file. Intellisense fails.

I guarantee I only have one instance of Xamarin open.

I have had this issue on two Macs (2012 era, and 2016 era), stable channels of Xamarin, and I'm very confident this isn't related to T9 templates or EF-style code generation.

These are POCOs with some methods.

What should I do next?

Comment: Hi,@LamonteCristo

I have the same problem. Any news about that?

Comment: I was so frustrated w/that I started doing development on Parallels + Win 10.  Then I gave up, found an article to delete Everything from Xamarin Studio, (preferences, cache, etc)... and reinstalled. No problems since.. however most of my time has been on other IDE's (non MSFT).

Comment: Recently, Visual Studio for Mac was released. I switch to VS and now all works as expected - it's a painless process ;)